Kafka DefaultErrorHandler not able to have stateful retry
I am using spring cloud stream. With stateful retry what I expect is this:
With the Spring Kafka ‘stateful’ retry, the retry can be safely as long as you like. So long as the maximum delay for any single retry is less than the consumer poll timeout. When the retryable exception is thrown the processing ends and the event is re-polled from the topic, so the consumer poll time starts again. The ‘stateful’ part means that the same consumer instance that is polling this topic partition knows how many retries it has done for this message, and hence when the retries are exceeded it can dead letter the message.
Based on following doc I implemented the following config
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> customizer() {
    return (container, destinationName, group) -> {
        DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(
            new FixedBackOff(1000L, 6L)
        );
        if (container.getCommonErrorHandler() == null) {
            container.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        }
    };
}

To verify, I set my max.poll.interval.ms: 3000, and since my timespan between each retry was less than the max poll time, it should not have caused any problem.
But when I ran, I see my event getting retried 6 times first and next time 3 times only. And then it continued to retry 3 times for each failed event. I am not sure if that is happening due to rebalancing because of the consumer being idle.
I read following blog where it used SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to achieve stateful retries. And since stceh is depracated I am using DefaultErrorHandler but not able to achieve the statefulness.
